# How do I check if many-to-many row already exists in sqlalchemy to prevent duplicate?

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

Here is code for my models:

```
class IllustratorAsset(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    uploader = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    project = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('project.id'))
    fragments = db.relationship('AssetFragment', backref='ai', lazy='dynamic')
    file_hash = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True)
    file_name = db.Column(db.String(128))
    
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Picture {}>'.format(self.id)

tags_association = db.Table(
    'tags_association',
    db.Column('fragment_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('asset_fragment.id'),index=True),
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('tag.id'),index=True),
    PrimaryKeyConstraint('fragment_id', 'tag_id')
)

class AssetFragment(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    asset = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('illustrator_asset.id'))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    uploader = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=tags_association, backref='fragments', lazy='dynamic')
    file_name = db.Column(db.String(128))
    file_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))

class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Tag {}>'.format(self.tag)
```

The idea is illustrations storage, there is **Asset** (Adobe Illustrator file), it has **Fragments** (renders of its different fragments), the fragment has some **Tags** for quick search which should be working through many-to-many relationship **tags_association**.

Currently, I'm stuck at trying to check if an association already exists, I'm sure there is some simple way to do it, but I'm missing some point. I came up with the code below, and I still get the exception of constraints.

```
for tag in new_tags: #list of tags from form
            t = Tag.query.filter_by(tag=tag).first()
            if (t is not None) and not(t in fragment.tags):
                fragment.tags.append(t)
            else:
                new_tag = Tag(tag=tag)
                if not(new_tag in fragment.tags):
                    fragment.tags.append(new_tag)
```

DB is Postgres

Answer (score 0):

Well answer came shortly after I've tried to do it in flask shell. [Shell output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnPcf.png)

I've realized, that it seems to be something wrong with the comparator, simple override makes it work:

```
def __eq__(self, __o: object) -> bool:
        return self.tag == __o.tag
```

Also needed to change checking by a bit:

```
for tag in new_tags:
            t = Tag.query.filter_by(tag=tag).first()
            if t is None:
                new_tag = Tag(tag=tag)
                print(new_tag)
                if not(new_tag in fragment.tags):
                    fragment.tags.append(new_tag)
            else:
                print(t)
                if not(t in fragment.tags):
                    fragment.tags.append(t)
```